# Using Euler's Theorem to find remainders

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am asked to find $34^{82248}$ mod $(83)$.I get this down to $34^{5}$ mod $(83),$ but stuck here. I am assuming acquiring the answer should require computing something like $34^{5}$. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

$$\phi(83)=82\text{ and }82248\equiv2\pmod{82}$$

Using Fermat's Little Theorem, $$(a,83)=1\implies a^{82}\equiv1\pmod{83}$$

$$\implies34^{82248}\equiv34^2\pmod{83}$$ which can be handled using normal division

Comment: hmm, seems simple enough. I wonder how i didn't see this. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: @user168593, How have you reached at $$34^5\pmod{83}?$$

Comment: i started looking at $82248$ mod $(83)$ to use the fact that $34^{83}$ would be congruent to $34$ by Fermat's Little theorem. So i kept dividing the exponent by $83$ and eventually reached $34^{5}$

Comment: @user168593, Oh. Hope now you understand the advantage of reaching at $1$

Comment: much better number to reach :)

Comment: Note $34^2=68\times 17\equiv -15\times 17 = -3\times 85\equiv -6$