# Using Euler Theorem to Determine Remainder

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am doing some self-study in number theory.

One of the exercises has got me stumped:

> Find the remainder of 34<sup>82248</sup> divided by 83. (Hint: Euler’s theorem.)

I know that 34 and 83 are relative primes (and by extension 34<sup>82248</sup> and 83), or that **gcd(34, 83) = 1**.

Someone has already asked this question ([Using Euler's Theorem to find remainders](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/915073/using-eulers-theorem-to-find-remainders)), but I don't think the answer given is correct (they suggest it's 77, and python says it's 4). I know that repeat questions are a stack exchange deadly sin; but I'm rephrasing the question with a bit more detail in the hope someone can enlighten me. If there's a better way I can get a satisfactory answer to the question - I'll happily adopt it.

Comment: No, the answer there is correct, and wolframalpha confirms it. If you asked python to calculate directly $34^{82248}\mod 83$, then perhaps you have rounding or range issues.

Comment: In python, typing print((34**82248)%83) gives me $77$.

Comment: In python, at least in python 3.x, you can also do pow(34, 82248, 83).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can verify the answer quickly with simple *mental* arithmetic as follows:

By Euler's theorem we know that $\, \color{#c00}{34^{82}\equiv 1}\pmod{83}$

Note $\,{\rm mod}\ 82\!:\ 82248 \equiv 248\equiv 3(82)+2\equiv 2,\ $  so $\,\ 82248 = 2+82 N$

Thus ${\rm mod}\ 83\!:\ 34^{\large 82248}\!\equiv 34^{\large 2+82N}\!\equiv 34^{\large 2} (\color{#c00}{34^{\large 82}})^{\large N}\!\equiv 34^{\large 2} \color{#c00}1^{\large N}\!\equiv 34^{\large 2}$

and $\ 34^2 \equiv 2^2 17^2\equiv 68\cdot 17\equiv -15\cdot 17\equiv -3\cdot 85\equiv -3(2)\equiv -6$

Comment: So if any number x starts with the digits in n, then in mod n it's equivalent to x with n truncated off the beginning? That's a handy trick.

Comment: @Aidenhjj $\ {\rm mod}\ \color{#c00}{82}:\ 82xyz \equiv \color{#c00}{82}(1000) + xyz\equiv xyz\ $ by $\ \color{#c00}{82}\equiv 0\ $

Comment: isnt this the same as my answer!

Comment: @vidyarthi The point was to show how to verify the answer with *purely mental arithmetic*. Of course both use Euler's theorem since that was the hinted method.

Answer (score 1):

By Euler's(or Fermat's)Theorem, $34^{82}\equiv 1$ mod($83$). Therefore, $34^{82246}=34^{(82)(1003)}\equiv1$ mod($83$). Thus, required answer is residue of $34^2$ mod ($83$) which is readily found to be $77$